# How can I use the split method without affecting the split value?

Tags: vb.net, methods, split

I was trying to split a string array, but the problem is when I try this code:

```
Dim str As String() = Split(RichTextBox1.Text, ".torrent")
```

then the result will come without the ".torrent" part. Is there a way I can split it without removing the word from the array?

For example:

```
Dim String1 As String= "A|B|C"
```

And by using split:

```
Dim str As String() = Split(String1, "|")
```

Then the result will be:

A B C

but without `|`, I want it to split the string, but leave the `|` alone.

Comment: What is the desired result on A|B|C? Where do you want to keep the character(s), on the left or on the right side or on both which would double them?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess he wants this result: `"A","|","B","|","C"`

Comment: You've already shown your effort, which is a good start. However, I think your question is part of the problem, which has an easier solution. The above definitely sounds like hacking. Please describe your original problem, i.e. input and expected result, so we can suggest a better solution. I am mostly positive there exists at least one.

Comment: Actually there is no hacking ?! but i was thinking to make program that download the torrents for me every day without me dealing with it , so i found this text file full with texts but the problem is the text file has a lot of unwanted texts and my plan was to clear the unwanted text then i could deal with it i will give you one line of the text to be sure:

Comment: E5070AAAC623B8DEA075B6AA3A7C0A5F6E491A79|Nikita S04E05 720p HDTV X264-DIMENSION|TV|http://kickass.to/nikita-s04e05-720p-hdtv-x264-dimension-t8413164.html|http://torcache.net/torrent/E5070AAAC623B8DEA075B6AA3A7C0A5F6E491A79.torrent
The Document have almost 4280 Lines , and this is just example .

Comment: @FahadAlkamli: Please include additional informations like your last comment in your question itself (instead of as comment) properly formatted next time.

Comment: well Mr  Tim Schmelter, i can't edit my question if you asked for more information, because acutely i didn't think anybody suspect that there is any hacking include, so thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex with so-called [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> Positive lookahead (...) q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, without making the u part of the match.

so it will be `(?<=[|])` in your case, making each `|` treated as a match for split, but magically not taken into account when calculating values. So the code will be:

```
Dim str as String =  "A|B|C"
Dim r = Regex.Split(str, "(?<=[|])")
```

which will result into `"A|"`, `"B|"` and `C`.

Comment: +1. This is something I did not know before about Regex.

Comment: Found it i need to Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Comment: I just had one problem when i replace the split mark in your code "|" with something like that ".torrent" then the output get confused  and the program split the word ".torrent" by litter 
this what will happen :
Tr
y.
t
o
r
r
e
n
t
Tr
y2.
t
o
r
r
e
n
t

I post in the Text box:Try.torrentTry2.torrent <Any help?

Comment: When i use one mark to split the string then the output is Fine and worked and the output will be something like that:
Try/
Try2/
Try3

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim ApplyTo As String = "Test1,Test2"
asd = ApplyTo.Split(",")
Console.WriteLine(asd(0)) 'Prints "Test1"
Console.WriteLine(asd(1)) 'Prints "Test2"
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your code it  want bring me  the output 
asd(0)="Test1"
And asd(1)= ","
 and asd(2) ="Test2" 
This what i want to split the string but leave the comma as it is .